# How to configure logstash in docker compose?

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I'm setting up a Docker container, but not able to configure the logstash to the elasticsearch which is running in AWS.

**The folder structure is as below**

```
.
├── logstash
│   └── logstash.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── file.jar
```

**./logstash/logstash.conf file look like**

(log folder in below input path will create automatically parallel to the jar file when we start the server using jar)

```
input {

  file {
          path => "/java_pro/log/*/*/*.log"
          type => "json"
        }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
         hosts => [ "https://search-***********.es.amazonaws.com:443" ]
         index => "logback-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
   }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8
RUN mkdir -p /java_pro
WORKDIR /java_pro
COPY . /java_pro
EXPOSE 443
CMD java -jar file.jar
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
hub:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/java_pro
    - static_volume:/java_pro
  networks:
    - rabbitmq-networks
rabbitmq:
  image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
  volumes:
    - "rabbitmq_data:/data"
  networks:
    - rabbitmq-networks
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=****
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=****
logstash:
  image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.4.0
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
  command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d
  environment:
    LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
  networks:
    - rabbitmq-networks

networks:
  rabbitmq-networks:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
  static_volume:
```

**Elasticsearch is up and running in AWS.**
Getting error while running using docker-compose up

```
No config files found in path {:path=>"/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf"}
Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elasticsearch:9200/, :path=>"/"}
Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch"}
```

How to resolve the above error and want to push all the logs from the application to elasticsearch using logstash.

Comment: Its trying to connect to the default elasticsearch. You could try volume mount the configuration into the default location for logstash. e.g `- ./logstash/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf` you shouldn't need the `command` line either then

Answer (score 9):

You mounted a file as the name of a directory here:

```
volumes:
    - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d
```

Include the filename when mounting a single file:

```
volumes:
    - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf:ro
```

I've also marked it read only since the container is likely not modifying this file.